# How to make JTextPane line break

Tags: java, swing, line-breaks, jtextpane

In Java Swing, the `JTextPane` has word wrap when the text exceeds *width*, but it does NOT line break for when there's a very long non-space string.

How can I make a  `JTextPane` line break for a long non-space string?

Any ideas would be much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: http://java-sl.com/tip_letter_wrap_java7.html you have to define min width for label view = 0

Comment: Also  this http://java-sl.com/tip_java7_text_wrapping_bug_fix.html could help

Comment: @StanislavL, Thanks, I tried solution of your first link. I get  java.lang.ClassCastException: javax.swing.text.DefaultStyledDocument cannot be cast to javax.swing.text.html.HTMLDocument
 at javax.swing.text.html.ParagraphView.getStyleSheet(ParagraphView.java:132)

Comment: My example has no relation to HTMLDocument at all. Don't know whta's wrong with **your code**

Comment: ok, I will investigate on this, maybe my code did something messy

Comment: @StanislavL, It turned out that I imported wrong ParagraphView. Your solution works like a charm, please considering put your comments as an answer for other people's reference. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To allow letter wrap `LabelView` should be modified to override min width

[java-sl.com/tip_letter_wrap_java7.html](http://java-sl.com/tip_letter_wrap_java7.html) you have to define min width for label view = 0

Also this [java-sl.com/tip_java7_text_wrapping_bug_fix.html](http://java-sl.com/tip_java7_text_wrapping_bug_fix.html) could help

Posted as an answer from my comment.

Comment: slapitsky (a) gmail.com