# JTextPane line break

Tags: java, swing, line, word-wrap, jtextpane

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23883475/how-to-make-jtextpane-line-break), the inquirer says

> The JTextPane do have word wrap when text exceeded width

This does not seem to be the case.

```
scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);

this.contentPane.add(scrollPane);

txtrFghj = new JTextPane();
txtrFghj.setBorder(null);
txtrFghj.setContentType("text/html");
txtrFghj.setText(content);

scrollPane.setViewportView(txtrFghj);
```

In the given code excerpt, `content`'s content will not wrap at all, it simply exceedes the visible size of the window. Long sentences cannot be seen completely, if the window is not big enough.

How can I achieve line wrapping?

I tried

```
txtrFghj.setSize(50,50);
```

but this does not change any behaviour at all.

Comment: `txtrFghj.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 50));` or such.

Comment: See the letter wrap for html http://java-sl.com/tip_html_letter_wrap.html if you need more customization of the wrap logic this http://java-sl.com/wrap.html could be useful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Guillaume, I figured it out, it took me three hours to realize though: Line break very much indeed **does** work here, but string break is not working, as can be seen in the [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23883475/how-to-make-jtextpane-line-break) which was quoted in the question.

My `JTextPane` content looked like the following:

```
<html>
   <body>
    <br>
    <font color="red">bla bla bla bla</font>\r\n
    <u>someVeeeeeeeeeeeeeryLooooongString__WithOUTanySpacesInBetweeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeen</u>
    <b>more text</b>
    // ........ a lot of more HTML
    Some funny SENTENCE which is longer than JTextPane.getSize().width usually allows. This sentence was NOT LINE WRAPPED which made me ask the question.
   </body>
</html>
```

Now, the SENTENCE would have been line-wrapped, if the *VeeeeryLooongString* had not *expanded* the JTextPane's width.
All the time, I hadn't thought of the long String within my TextPane Object and how it could have affected the overall line wrapping behaviour.

Deleting this giga-String solved the issue for me.

For further information on this topic, see this detailed [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7036543/how-is-word-wrapping-implemented-in-jtextpane-and-how-do-i-make-it-wrap-a-strin).

Now I am going to try to enable String wrapping within JTextPanes, for which further information can again be found in the quoted [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23883475/how-to-make-jtextpane-line-break).

Edit.: Letter-wrapping can be done, but it seems line-breaks `<br>` are not working anymore then. For the given question, the easiest workaround will be **not** to disable the horizontal scrollbar and set it to `AS_NEEDED` instead:

```
scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
```

Answer (score 4):

There must be something else in your code that prevents this from working correctly.

Here is a small demo example with the same code that runs just fine:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextPane;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class TestLineWrap {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new TestLineWrap().initUI();
            }
        });

    }

    protected void initUI() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JTextPane editorPane = new JTextPane();
        editorPane.setContentType("text/html");
        editorPane
                .setText("<html>Some long text that cannot hold on a single line if the screen is too small</html>");
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(editorPane);
        scrollPane
        .setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
        frame.add(scrollPane);
        frame.setSize(200, 400);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```